# configure.py: error: no such option: --no-use-shipped-boost

Tags: python, pycuda, tensorrt

I tried to installing pycuda using `https://github.com/jkjung-avt/tensorrt_demos/blob/master/ssd/install_pycuda.sh` as i use python3 .

So while installing I run into a error :

> Usage: configure.py [options]
>
> configure.py: error: no such option: --no-use-shipped-boost

**My system Configuration :**

Google Cloud - ubuntu 18.04

CUDA 10.0

TENSORRT 6x

I'm trying to install Pycuda 2019.1.2

For installation reference, 
`https://github.com/jkjung-avt/tensorrt_demos`     ->>> Demo #4: YOLOv3

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://github.com/jkjung-avt/tensorrt_demos/issues/214):
Just remove the file "${HOME}/src/pycuda-2019.1.2/siteconf.py".

So it should be like this:
`cd ${HOME}/src/pycuda-2019.1.2/` 
then
`rm siteconf.py`

Then you should be able to run the install again.